# What does single vertical bar and equals bar mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, what does `|=` operator do?

**Example:**

```
a = 23
a |= 3333 # => 3351
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The single vertical bar is a bitwise OR operator.

`a |= 3333` is equivalent to `a = a | 3333`

Answer (score 10):

`|=` is called syntactic sugar.

In Ruby `a = a | 3333` is the same as `a |= 3333`.

`|` means

> Binary OR Operator copies a bit if it exists in either operand.[**Ruby Bitwise Operators**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm)